# Azure VM disk performance dropped sharply

Tags: performance, azure, cloud, virtual-machine

As title really.

I was extracting a 5GB database from a zip and this happened:

http://cl.ly/image/3b1c1E0X1E2J/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-24%20at%2022.54.58.png

Any thoughts on the sudden drop in speed?

Using a 'standard' A3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Azure support team regarding this issue and they explained that the temporary disk on the VM should be used as much as possible for these types of activities.

I hope this helps anyone else that encounters performance related issues.